# Register Joomla 2.5 component manually in the database

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

How can I register Joomla 2.5 components manually in the database? because table structure is different than 1.5 version. In 1.5 components can be added to jos_components table. Now, it seems prefix_extensions table. Can anybody tell what are the parameters? or if i'm not correct, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't register components manually in the SQL, they get added to the database upon installation. Just install the components via the Extension Manager in the Joomla backend and make sure they are Joomla 2.5 compatable.

Answer (score 3):

This SQL query does what you want (just insert your own values and don't forget to change the table prefix '#_'):

```
INSERT INTO `#__extensions`
(`extension_id`, `name`, `type`, `element`, `folder`, `client_id`, `enabled`)
VALUES (0, 'My Great App', 'component', 'com_mygreatapp', '', 1, 1 )
```